# How to sort points to construct a polygon in python?

Tags: python, sorting, polygon

I have a data of x and y that I want to construct a polygon representing this data. To do that I should sort the points in a way that lines representing the polygon are drawn correctly. How can I do that in python? I think there should be a double constrain or something, one for the angle and the other is for the distance maybe. Any ideas?!

The data is in here: [Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s_IDZ1ZzSWB_qnNZ4ecpK5GiCkJnRgO_/view?usp=sharing)

what I want is something like this:
[image]

I have tried the following code but the result is incorrect:

```
mean = np.mean(data, axis=0)
# Compute angles
angles = np.arctan2((data-mean)[:, 1], (data-mean)[:, 0])
# Transform angles from [-pi,pi] -> [0, 2*pi]
angles[angles < 0] = angles[angles < 0] + 2 * np.pi
# Sort
sorting_indices = np.argsort(angles)
sorted_data = data[sorting_indices]
```

Here is what it result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In a list of 58 points there is more then one possible polygon, even if you rule out self-intersecting ones.

The problem you are encountering is that your list of points basically does not have enough information to allow you to select only one of the possibilities.
(*Unless* for example the sequence of the points in the list is relevant, which doesn't seem to be the case here.)

Comment: any ideas to get the desired result?

Comment: It is not possible.